# How do we make sure using nifi that a file is processing only once while handling HTTP Requests

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to read files from HTTP requests. I want to make sure that a file is processed only once and not processed again even if we add the file to source path again.

Wanted to avoid duplicate files being processed again

Is there any way we can achieve it using NIFI?

Pretty much new to working on these parts.

Comment: store unique identifier of the file in database or cache. and then check if it's already processed.

Comment: the number of files inflow is too high(300 files per sec) and cannot be stored in cache. Apart from adding one more layer like storing in DB can we leverage any nifi processor to achieve it

Comment: just check [this](https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks) for example:  SET: 74239 requests per second. dedicated cache servers are extremely fast.